# Displaying Korean letters in Tkinter GUI on Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My aim is to create a window that can show Korean letters in the window. 
My method is to read it from a file, containing Korean letters. Let say, the file only contains:

```
안녕하세요
```

My problem is that, when i tried this code:

```
... #codes above
f = open("file")
content = f.read()
tk.Label(root, text = content).grid()
... #codes below
```

the output became:

```
#assuming this is the window of the tkinter
ì•ˆë…•í•˜ì„¸ìš”
```

I looked up youtube, and the solution here does not help. [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQkaBiOwsIo&t=384s)

I tried to improvise from that too, tried to decode and encode like this

```
from codecs import encode, decode

... #parts of the code

f = open("file")
fetchcontent = f.read()
content = encode(fetchcontent, "utf-8")
print (content) #output to console
tk.Label(root, text = decode(content, "quoted-printable").grid() #output to GUI
```

the output from console is

```
b'\xc3\xac\xe2\x80\xa2\xcb\x86\xc3\xab\xe2\x80\xa6\xe2\x80\xa2\xc3\xad\xe2\x80\xa2\xcb\x9c\xc3\xac\xe2\x80\x9e\xc2\xb8\xc3\xac\xc5\xa1\xe2\x80\x9d'
```

Because from the Youtube Video it showed \u instead of \x, I tried to look method to decode \x , hence the line *decode(content, "quoted-printable")*
However, the output to the GUI became

```
Ã¬â¢ËÃ«â¦â¢Ã­â¢ËÃ¬âÂ¸Ã¬Å¡â
```

Is there any solution to this? My goal is to just display some Korean letters, now it just severely confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I found my answer.

Instead of

```
f = open(file)
```

I should have used

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(file, encoding = "utf-8")
```